# trying to create a database but I got a mysql error [Syfony2]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpmyadmin

I created an entity on symfony 2, and now I'm trying to create a database using the console command :

```
 php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

and it generates this error :

```
Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on     '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

My OS is Mac OS x , with MAMP

and my paramaters file is :

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Comment: Was the error message not obvious enough? :( It's unable to connect to your MySQL server on localhost.. Check the MySQL server instance!

Comment: Empty root password? I'm glad to hear it didn't work :P

Comment: @Mike: Though undesired, you can still connect with no password specified.

Comment: Yikes! That's just about as bad as an empty password.

Comment: Even worse actually. I hope I never use a website that connects to its database with those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL by default runs on port `3306`.  If you haven't changed that port then use:

```
database_port: 3306
```

If you have changed the port then use the changed port instead and give it a try.

Comment: Oooooh many thanks, I found at least the error, 

    parameters:    database_port: 8889
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: root

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to write this :

```
database_password: null > database_password: ''
```

Your user have the goods permissions ?